# Is there a keyboard shortcut to clear the search box in Lion's Mail?

Tags: keyboard, mail.app

I am running 10.7.2 and would like to be able to clear the search box in Mail with a shortcut. How do I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the focus is on the search box press "esc" key.
If not, the fastest way I've found is by first pressing Option+Command+F to set the focus on the search box and then press esc to clear it.

This is a link to apple standard shorcuts: [Mac OS X Shorcuts](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1343)

Answer (score 1):

I love [Keyboard Maestro](https://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/) for this kind of stuff (and in general). I've bound cmd-shift-delete to a macro that clears the search box. [Here's](http://pastebin.com/tnfU70AQ) the macro. I'd add a screenshot but don't have the required reputation yet.

Comment: Any ideas on how to run this script in BetterTouchTool? I am able to run AppleScript or JavaScript in BTT but no plist files (as in the macro) and am lacking the skills to convert one into the other. -- I am aware that comments are not the place for follow-up questions but felt it was not worth a question on its own.

Comment: Yeah, bind it to a sequence of shortcuts: 1. whatever you have bound for `Edit;Find;Mailbox Search` 2. ⌘-A  3. ⌫ . 

OR

just do ⌘2 ⌘1 where ⌘1 is your favourite mailbox - switching mailboxes clears out the search text :)